# jQuery friend selector. With jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

I have made a jquery friend filter.
I have a big ul list with a lot of friends names.

I have a search box and when you search in this box you get a live result page.

When you click a friend the li item gets an active class which overlays a green icon on it.

Here you can see it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBbH3/)

But now my problem.

Next to the search bar I have a link called "Now select". 
When you click on this link I want to only show the li items that have an active class - with the green icon.

I am a beginning javascripter.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having some trouble understanding. What is supposed to happen when you click "Now select"? From the page context I'm guessing you want to select (green tick, same as clicking them) all the people currently matching the search. Is that correct?

Comment: You have a lot people in the list. When you click on a li item. Than the li item is selected. The li item get a class active. But this is a litle broken and not working good. That is the first problem. When you click on the li item. The li item must get a active class.

When you click on the Now Select. Than all  the li items that have an active class must be show. The li items with none active class must be hide. Do you understad it?

Comment: I corrected your English, let me know if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Mike wants

```
$("#nowSel").click(function() {
    $("li:not(.active)").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/n69Rm/

Possibly with a test

```
$("#nowSel").click(function() {
  var selected = $("li .active");
  if (selected.length>0) {
    $("li:not(.active)").hide();
  }
  else {
   // tell user to select something
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it? I got the impression it was that + $("li.active").show() so that it also shows currently hidden, but active friends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/CBbH3/2/

Probably it needs to be refactored a little, but in short you need to use `:visible` filter for this:

```
$('#now-select').click(function() {
        $(".friend-selection li:visible")
            .addClass("active")
            .append('<span class="check"></div>')
            .find(".check").fadeIn(150);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: This is not what i looking for. Sorry for my bad english. 
I try it as clearly as possible.

Comment: I didn't get it _So, when i click on "Now select". Than the li items with active class must show_. Where it should be shown?

Answer (score 0):

you can change this line

```
<a href="#" title="Now Select" >Now Select<a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" title="Now Select" id ="nowselect">Now Select<a>
```

then define this.

```
$("#nowselect").click(){

    var active =$.("li.active");
    //write your logic with active live
}
```

Comment: $("nowselect") should be $("#nowselect"). And it should be .click(function () { ... });